# Can't extend my drive: “There is not enough space available on the disk to complete this operation”

Tags: windows, hard-drive, partitioning, ssd, disk-management

“There is not enough space available on the disk to complete this operation”: [image: disk_management]

Why am I getting this error? I've just decided to run linux on a VM to speed up the change between OS and ripped of my Ubuntu to set the things. But now I can't extend my SSD's partition using the Windows' tool. Did some google and found different reasons behind the same issue.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: You forgot to say which partition you are trying to extend? By how much? What does Ubuntu have to do with all this?

Comment: There can be different reasons for this error message, we will need more informations. What have you tried so far to fix it yourself?

Comment: I'm trying to extend C: partition.

Comment: From the image, there should be no problem with extending the C partition, *unless you are specifying a larger size than is available in the Unallocated space*. If this is not the problem, try a third-party product such as [EaseUS Partition MasterFree](https://www.easeus.com/partition-manager/epm-free.html).

Comment: You have not provided any feedback on the answers posted. That is an essential way to help others help you.

Comment: I've done it using Linux. Thx

Answer (score 0):

I also faced similar issue earlier.
I was unable to extend or make small my any partition with Windows' in built 'Disk Management'.

Then, I used 'AOMEI Partition Assistant' on someone's suggestion and it worked without errors, but it do suggest to backup your files, otherwise if anything wrong happens you may lose all your data.

As @harrymc suggested you may also use 'EaseUS Partion MasterFree'. By the way, you can use any reliable 3rd party software.

As you are trying to do operations on system partition, I would suggest you to make a Bootable Media in case your partition get corrupted. (AOMEI Free edition have this feature)

For me extend operation on system partion didn't cause any errors, but it depends on system to system.

Answer (score 0):

From the image, there should be no problem with extending the C partition over
the Unallocated space.

Perhaps you are specifying a larger size than is available in the Unallocated space.
Device Manager should automatically suggest the right size,
so better accept the suggested value.

If this is not the problem, try a third-party product such as
[EaseUS Partition MasterFree](https://www.easeus.com/partition-manager/epm-free.html).
If you are still encountering a problem, try it again while booting in Safe mode.
If this also does not succeed, try another product that has a bootable disk
and try booting from it rather than from Windows.

If nothing works, then the disk itself has a hardware problem.

Answer (score -1):

This answer about errors on *shrinking* partitions
https://superuser.com/a/1323010/151755
was very useful to me a while ago. Maybe you will be able to find out why you can't grow that partition following the same procedure:

*main steps copied here in case the original answer is edited or removed*

1. Once again, attempt to shrink *(grow)* the partition. You should get the
   "There is not enough space" error.
2. Launch Windows' Event Viewer application.
3. In Event Viewer, go to Windows Logs > Application.
4. Find and Click a recent log of type Warning. It should have the message,
   "Error: during volume shrink initiated on volume Windows (C:) we
   failed to move a movable file extent." ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zzw7.png))

If you're interested, see the rest of the answer at https://superuser.com/a/1323010/151755 (and upvote it).

Comment: Why the downvote??

Answer (score -1):

You have to delete the logical parition on the right first then you can expand the primary partitions.
The fact that there is no volume in the logical partitions is confusing you.

Comment: Look again, space next to the partition is unallocated.