# Windows Disk Partition showing wrong capacity for dual boot

Tags: linux, windows, dualboot

I want to make dual boot Windows and Fedora. I currently have Windows 11. When I want to shrink my disk (C:) it says there is only 18044 available. Which is 18 GB. This PC shows that there is 170 GB free out of 475 GB. I don't know how to convince Windows that there is enought space.

Also what is the recommended space for another OS? I was thinking 30 GB should do it. I intend to use Linux mainly for programming.

Thanks for help.

Comment: This has been asked so often, often with slight variations. Does this answer your question? [Cannot shrink C: partition: Not enough space](https://superuser.com/questions/1063692/cannot-shrink-c-partition-not-enough-space)

Comment: I think its a bad idea. It will xause issues with Window updates and Windows crashes. Its better to buy a larger disk.

Comment: `gparted` can handle this. See [here](https://superuser.com/a/1804927/1787250) for a step by step howto with a Linux Life system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @dodrg mentioned, I had to use a 3-party app. GParted would work as well as what I used, which is AOMEI Partition Assistant.

I had no problems using the app, very user-friendly. No problem with shrinking the disk to make up space for Linux.

Conclusion, it was Windows's fault.

Answer (score -1):

This is due to unmovable files created by windows such as paging files, system protection files, etc. So, 18044 is the available space before we hit an unmovable file. 
Check this page out- https://ugetfix.com/ask/solved-cannot-shrink-a-volume-beyond-the-point-where-any-unmovable-files-are-located/

**Remember** to enable the disabled options later.

Also, just in case you need to see which particular file is causing the issue, you can do so by first checking how much volume space can be shrinked (in order for windows to create the log) and then following these steps-

- Launch *Run* by pressing *Win*+R
- Type in *Event Viewer*
- Go to Windows Logs -> Applications and check for where it says "defrag" (For me, it was event ID 259)

Also, unless you are not installing multiple heavy-weight softwares for development, I think 30GB is good enough. 
Do ask in case of further doubt!!

Comment: I dont see how this helps and doesnt take into account updates and crashes.