# Shrink a Windows volume containing "System Volume Information" on the end of the drive

Tags: windows, hard-drive, partitioning

I need to shrink volume on which my windows resides. Following [How to shrink Windows 7 boot partition with unmovable files](https://superuser.com/questions/88131/how-to-shrink-windows-7-boot-partition-with-unmovable-files)
I discovered that the file which "blocks" my volume from shrinking is

> \System Volume Information{eb2336fd-5fc7-11e7-adc5-185e0f8922b2}{3808876b-c176-4e48-b7ae-04046e6cc752}::$DATA

Is it possible to move it and shrink the disk?

EDIT: My question concerns SSD hard drive.

Comment: I know that [Defraggler](https://www.piriform.com/defraggler) has a tool called "Compact free space" or something like that. Basically, it shifts every occupied space at the begining of the partition. However, since `System Volume Information` is a system forler, I don't know if this will work.

Comment: Thanks for info Nathan, I forgot to mention this is SSD hard drive - Defraggler is (as far as I know) HDD defragmentation tool. I have already tried Windows Defragmentation tool and it didn't help. I have edited my question accordingly.

Comment: This should still apply to an SSD. We are not trying to defragment to improve performance (which makes sense on an HDD, but not on an SSD), we are trying to shove all occupied blocks to the same end of the *physical* disk. This makes sense for both HDDs and SSDs, since data has to be located *somewhere* on the disk in both cases.

Comment: I am also having this problem!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I shrink a Windows 10 partition?](https://superuser.com/questions/1017764/how-can-i-shrink-a-windows-10-partition)

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 11, I was able to deal with the same System Volume Information file with the following solution.

[How can I shrink a Windows 10 partition?](https://superuser.com/questions/1017764/how-can-i-shrink-a-windows-10-partition)

Comment: Please don't answer with a link to a post, just declare the question as a duplicate.