# How can I get maximum space to shrink from C drive

Tags: windows-10

I have Bought new laptop which contains only C drive with 915.84 GB of space ,in which 874 GB is free ,when i want to partition the space ,the only available space  to Shrink is 467994 MB [467.994 GB],why it is like ,can any one help me in this ,I need to keep C drive as 150GB and remaining space i want to shrink it to new drives

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Partition the drive using the disk management snap-in.

Comment: also https://superuser.com/questions/1017764/how-to-shrink-a-windows-10-partition/1060508

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using a **different partitioning tool**. Try *Mini Partition Wizard* / *AOMEI Partition Manager* if on Windows. Else if on Linux use *GParted* or maybe you can get the *GParted* Live iso.

Basically the Amount you can shrink from C drive is the minimum space required by the Windows system(i.e. approx 12-14 GB's).