# How can I recover disk space used up by System Volume Information

Tags: windows-7

My laptop has 120GB disk space. It runs Windows 7.
When I use 'SpaceSniffer', find out that 'System Volume Information' uses up 32G of space. And it has 5 files: 20.6 G, 3.4 G, 3.2G, 3.1 G, 2.4 G.

How can I recovered those space used by  System Volume Information

Any my windows 7 restore point is already off.

Thank you.

Comment: http://lmgtfy.com/?q=clear+out+system+volume+information

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to turn off System Restore and remove System Volume Information folders in Windows?](http://superuser.com/questions/242760/how-to-turn-off-system-restore-and-remove-system-volume-information-folders-in-w)

Answer (score 6):

Here are some commands that you could use in the Command Prompt console in administrator mode in order to view and resize the space allocated for System Volume Information:

1. To see the space allocated and used for System Volume Information:

   - Open Command Prompt with “Run as Administrator” option
   - Type in: vssadmin list shadowstorage
   - You will see Used Space, Allocated Space and Maximum Space for System Volume Information
2. To see the restore information stored therein:

   - Use in the same console command: vssadmin list shadows
3. To resize the maximum allocated space:

   - Type in command: vssadmin resize shadowstorage /on=[here add the drive letter]: /For=[here add the drive letter]: /Maxsize=[here add the maximum size]
   - E.g., vssadmin resize shadowstorage /on=C: /For=C: /Maxsize=4GB
   - You will see a prompt confirming resize done
   - You can check the status again using the command discussed in point 1 above
4. Just to get rid of the space already consumed, but sticking to the same size of max-size as before:

   - Do actions as per step 3 to set the max-size t, say, 1GB
   - If you check now, most likely you’ll see that used space is now 0KB
   - Do the resize again and set it back to what it was before
   - Check your disk space availability in Windows Explorer, you should see the reclaim is done!

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Most of that is from System Restore although it does sound pretty high. Go to Control Panel - System - System Protection to see how much space is allocated to system restore. Adjust as necessary. Sometimes if you re-install windows you get system restore data from a previous install left on disk - the best way to get rid of this is to boot from a Linux live CD like Backtrack 5 and delete the files.

Answer (score 0):

You have it turned off, but the restore points are still there.

Goto to Desktop Cleanup:
Start Menu\Programs\Accessories\System Tools\Disk Cleanup

and then click "Clean up System Files" - More options