# How to identify which unmovable files are in the way of shrinking a partition

Tags: windows-7, partitioning

I cannot shrink Windows 7 OS partition because of some unmovable files. I was wondering how to identify these files, so that I might be able to search ways to move these files elsewhere. I read [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/88131/how-to-shrink-windows-7-boot-partition-with-unmovable-files/88739#88739), but don't understand how to identify. Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 1):

Many third-party defrag tools can show the organization of files on disk, for example, Auslogics Disk Defrag does this. In many of these clients you can visually see what clusters would sit in the way of a volume shrink, hover over them, and see the name of the file.

Comment: @jeremysturdivant-Where you can see this in Auslogics?