# How to clone only the Windows 7 system drive C: to new bootable SSD without cloning the data from separate drive F:?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot, ssd, clone

This question is similar to my situation but does not provide a definitive answer:

[How can I transfer Windows from a partition of an existing hard drive to a new (smaller) SSD?](https://superuser.com/questions/287171/how-can-i-transfer-windows-from-a-partition-of-an-existing-hard-drive-to-a-new)

It says clone the C: drive, but not the data drive, and then run System Repair.

I have a hard disk with Windows 7 system installed and three empty folders in the C: drive

> - C:\Users\UserName\Music
> - C:\Users\UserName\Pictures
> - C:\Users\UserName\Videos

but none of the other standard User folders appear there.

The same disk has a data drive F: with these folders with stored files

> - F:\Users\UserName\Contacts
> - F:\Users\UserName\Desktop
> - F:\Users\UserName\Documents
> - F:\Users\UserName\Downloads
> - F:\Users\UserName\Favorites
> - F:\Users\UserName\Links
> - F:\Users\UserName\Music
> - F:\Users\UserName\Pictures
> - F:\Users\UserName\Saved Games
> - F:\Users\UserName\Searches
> - F:\Users\UserName\Videos

I want to keep the data stored in the F: drive on the existing hard disk and clone only the C: drive to enable system boot from a new SSD.

What must I do before cloning the C: drive to the SSD so it will boot properly either with empty User folders in the default C: location or in the F: drive?

I don't mind rebuilding the F: drive on the SSD if necessary but I need the C: drive to boot without cloning any data.

Comment: I don't understand the question.  The folders you list are not required to boot Windows.  Why don't you just clone the drive and then redirect your profile again?  In other words, clone the drive and boot from the new SSD, keeping the profile in it's current location.

Comment: Do you mean clone the C: drive only to SSD, which will be bootable as is, and then I can  create the F: drive on the SSD afterward?

Comment: I would clone all partitions on the disk except for the data partition.  Your profile might encounter an error when you attempt to log into your account, at that time, I would recreate the data partition on the new disk. While it will complain about the profile being unable to be loaded, it should load a temporary profile, that exists on the system disk.

Comment: COMMENT, PART 1 ••• "rism's" answer on the other post is your solution (and I agree with rism that your partitions are disordered), You haven't responded to rism's solution yet. My view is that you should have a separate and unique, dedicated SSD or hdd drive for data only, and another for image backups. Your 500GB HDD and your new, 120GB SSD, will be two separate, unique OS's, that you cannot run at the same time, and you want to boot between them, with the SSD being able to access the F/Partition on the 500GB drive. This is what you are describing.

Comment: COMMENT, PART 2 ••• At https://superuser.com/questions/287171/how-can-i-transfer-windows-from-a-partition-of-an-existing-hard-drive-to-a-new you state: you confess, "The 500 GB has started to make weird noises, which is why I'm trying to replace it." ••• Then you ask for solutions to be able to access files on a drive... that you confess to wanting to replace... because it is making, "weird noises". Do you understand what I am warning about here?

Comment: COMMENT, PART 3 ••• You will find a solution from us (rism already has pointed to it), for your ability to access your data on the failing HDD, from another OS on a separate SSD, but at the end of the day, you will lose your data on your failing HDD, as you have just confessed you are aware of "weird noises" coming from it. You need to purchase (1) a larger SSD for your OS... (2) another Terabyte SSD or HDD for your Data. ••• Clone your current OS over to the new, larger SSD to have your original OS safe and intact...

Comment: COMMENT, PART 4 •••  THEN place ALL your data on the new Terabyte storage drive, and reconfigure your default folders in your cloned SSD to recognize the new paths to your new storage drive. Take the older 500GB drive and reformat it and use it to store non-essential items that you do not mind losing suddenly. Set up a recursive synchronization process (allwaysync?) from your 500GB "weird noises" HDD to a special folder on your new TB storage so that, if the 500GB fails" you still retain your data.

Comment: COMMENT, PART 5 •••  Good luck, dear friend, and all the very best to you and yours. Your data must contain irreplaceable memories of your loved ones, let alone history that you have spent countless hours collecting. Life is full of "weird noises" that we ignore and try to "work around", yes?

Comment: FINAL THOUGHT: Your 500GB "weird noises" HDD is like a structure condemned to demolition. Instead of repairing the failing supportive parts of it, first get your loved ones (F/Partition) moved out, and then demolish the building and rebuild it, and only use it for storage, not allowing loved ones back into it.