# Defrag NTFS $LogFile

Tags: windows-7, ntfs, sysinternals

I have the super descriptive "my computer is slow" issue. In resource manager I notice that c:\$LogFile access times are continuously around 800 ms, and I suspect this is causing much of the slowdown. At [How do you defragment the MFT on an NTFS disk?](https://superuser.com/questions/316003/how-do-you-defragment-the-mft-on-an-ntfs-disk) I found that `contig` could - in theory - help. In practice though, running `contig $LogFile` in a cmd window run as administrator gives me

```
Contig v1.7 - Makes files contiguous
Copyright (C) 1998-2012 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

------------------------
Access is denied.

No files fragmented.
```

`$Bitmap`, `$Boot`, and `$BadClus` also give me Access is denied.

`$Mft`, `$Volume`, `$AttrDef`, `$Secure`, `$UpCase` and `$Extend` work fine.

How can I work around this? Can I attach this disk to a different machine, not mount in some way, and defrag those files from there? If so, how would that work? Or are there simpler ways to do the same?

Comment: The consensus seems to be that you can't, but I'd be interested to see what happens to $LogFile after cloning the drive.  In my experience, unlike defrag utilities, cloning a drive makes every file contiguous.

Comment: The [TechNet page](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/sysinternals/bb897428.aspx) for Contig actually says: _Contig can also analyze and defragment the following NTFS metadata files: $LogFile_.  I also get access denied.

Comment: Running Contig as SYSTEM also didn't work. Maybe try running it from the recovery console or Windows PE environment?

Answer (score 2):

The $Logfile is a special NTFS system file. It is a circular log of all disk operations and is used to safely roll back unsuccessful disk operations. The file has a fixed size and is allocated when the disk is formatted. It cannot be deleted, moved, or defragmented.

The "chkdsk" Windows commandline utility can show and change the size of the $Logfile. Making the $Logfile bigger will not move it, but will append a new fragment. Making the $Logfile smaller will remove fragments from the end.

```
CHKDSK c: /L:XXX   
where XXX is the size in KB. /L without a size will show info.
```

You could try setting a smaller size temporarily, defrag and then resize it again.

Comment: If it can't be defragmented, why does contig explicitly mention $LogFile as a possible target?

Comment: Not sure. Have you tried Contig on a disk other than the one holding the operating system? I believe resizing a NTFS partition would reset the $LogFile, so maybe it is possible to defrag on a partition without any file locks on it.

Comment: The disk is a disk in my laptop, which has only place for one disk and not much room for experimentation of non-boot disks.

Comment: NTFS does not log "all disk operations" in $logfile. NTFS logging, two-phase commit, etc., is only for changes to file system metadata. It doesn't log (or allow rollbacks, etc.) of file content. http://ntfs.com/transaction.htm

Answer (score 0):

$LogFile records write operations on the hard disk and cannot be moved or defragmented.
Its access can only be slow if :

1. Your disk is slowing down, or
2. Many writes are being done to files.

In the first case, your hard disk is dying.

In the second case, some software is busily writing to the disk.

Some ideas for the second hypothesis are :

1. Run Task Manager and watch the "I/O Writes" column for processes
2. Boot in Safe mode. If the slow-down disappears, then some installed program is to blame.
   You could use [Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) to turn off startups until you find it.
3. Disable disk indexing
4. Disable Windows Media Sharing
5. Disable the antivirus
6. See if the antivirus is set to examine every open of a file

Answer (score -1):

If you suspect a hardware failure, I would suggest booting with a [Trinity Rescue Kit](http://trinityhome.org/) and performing hardware tests and scans with the software provided in that kit.

You will not be able to defragment system files that are in use. I would recommend rebooting into safe mode to minimize the number of files in use to allow the defragmenter to work efficiently.

1. **Reboot into Safe Mode**
2. While in safe mode, clear your temps and caches (right click on the drive in explorer and go to tools, use the cleanup)
3. While in safe mode, defragment.

I would also suggest the freeware [Defraggler](http://www.piriform.com/DEFRAGGLER)

Answer (score -1):

UltimateDefrag claims it can defrag all files as well as move/position any file whereever you want, change MFT size, etc. (Versión 5 i think).

The couterpart: It is paid software, not freeware.

So i can assume, some time in the future, maybe someone freeware will do the same.