# There is a way to move $MftMirr other then using PerfectDisk?

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, file-management, mft

I'm trying to resize a Windows 7 system partition, but I can't move some files placed in the middle of the volume. I'd like to shrink the partition further then by half and I don't like the idea of leaving those files at the very end of the new partition.

Right now the last file on the volume is \$MftMirr::$DATA I already went through the process of disabling pagefile, hibernation, restore points and other application folders to stop the system from using non consolidated space in the middle of the volume

I understand the partition may stop to work if I mess up with $MftMirr (which is why I didn't try gparted) and I read PerfectDisk should be able to move these files wothout a problem, but its free trial only lasts 30 days and I'd like not to use it.

There is a way to move $MftMirr (and other $* files) other then using PerfectDisk?

Comment: Gparted and partedmagic are both good tools I have used them frequently without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

Gparted and partedmagic are both good tools I have used them frequently without any issues.  Use either to resize the partition to it minimum possible size.  Then resize to max size and the files should be consolidated.

Comment: I'm worried because of this: http://superuser.com/questions/88131/how-to-shrink-windows-7-boot-partition-with-unmovable-files. It's a very old question and the problem probably was with a known bug in an older version of gparted. but I'm still worried.

Comment: in the end I tried gparted from a Linux Mint LiveUSB, but it didn't work. I just tried the GUI command and couldn't move the cursor further then from the starting measure. I may try with the most recent version and/or terminal commands, but I'd like to know if this situation sounds familiar to anyone..   (btw the orifginal size of the partition was about 186GB, right now it is 93.2GB with 40.5 free GB)

Comment: @maja Referring to your link, no gparted nor partedmagic will leave your windows 7 in a BSOD condition.  I have used it dozens of times and never experienced this error.

Comment: I also used gparted for a long time, anyways possibly breaking a Windows system or not, it seems it doesn't work for moving those system files starting with "$" (which are the "sensible" one). I'll try again with a newer build before discarting gparted but I kind of need the job done right now... if I have to go commercial I can as well use PerfectDisk trial and be done with it (if it even works now.. )