# Get rid of unmovable file, allowing to shrink a partition

Tags: windows-7, partitioning

I have a 300 GB HDD in a Windows 7 computer. The main partition C: in wich Windows is installed, was 280 GB, and yesterday had 120 GB of free space, but with "Disk management" a part of windows's program ["computer management"](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/windows7/ht/disk-management-windows-7.htm) the program could reduce C: but only by 30 GB, remaining 250 GB for C:, which is a reduction in size of only a quarter of the free space available.

This prompted me to search for answers, making me read [this great first answer](https://superuser.com/questions/88131/how-to-shrink-windows-7-boot-partition-with-unmovable-files/88157). I did the steps described in the answer except removing the file that it's producing the problem (I hope it's the one I suspect), because I don't know if I should try to remove or uninstall this file, and how do it  without causing severe problems if that's possible.

So, here are the reports result of following the [answer linked before](https://superuser.com/questions/88131/how-to-shrink-windows-7-boot-partition-with-unmovable-files/88157)

First, I searched on the Windows event log > application and found 2 events of ID 259, the ones referred in the answer, and they seem identical, so I will only reproduce the details of one of them:

Disclaimer: I know it's in spanish, I'm sorry for that: If you need I can translate it, no problem. But if you only need file location, then I don't need to translate it, also you may google translate.

```
Se inició un análisis de reducción de volumen en el volumen OS (C:). Esta entrada del registro de eventos contiene información acerca del último archivo no movible que podría limitar el número máximo de bytes reclamables.

 Detalles de diagnóstico:
 - El último archivo no movible parece ser: \ProgramData\Microsoft\Diagnosis\events01.rbs::$DATA
 - El último clúster del archivo es: 0x40b5688
 - Destino potencial de reducción (dirección LCN): 0x201538a
 - Las marcas de archivo NTFS son: ----D
 - Fase de reducción: <analysis>

 Para obtener más detalles acerca de este archivo, use el comando "fsutil volume querycluster \\?\Volume{d4dd19c7-01e3-11e2-9368-806e6f6e6963} 0x40b5688
```

I executed the command asked to execute in that report at the end. This is the result:

```
C:\Users\Nico>fsutil volume querycluster \\?\Volume{d4dd19c7-01e3-11e2-9368-806e
6f6e6963} 0x40b5688
Clúster 0x00000000040b5688 usado por ----D \ProgramData\Microsoft\Diagnosis\even
ts01.rbs::$DATA
```

It's the same info that's on the first report. At last , I include a more complete copy of all the report of the ID 259 event:

```
Nombre de registro:Application
Origen:        Microsoft-Windows-Defrag
Fecha:         18/12/2015 03:29:12 p.m.
Id. del evento:259
Categoría de la tarea:Ninguno
Nivel:         Información
Palabras clave:Clásico
Usuario:       No disponible
Equipo:        leon
Descripción:
Se inició un análisis de reducción de volumen en el volumen OS (C:). Esta entrada del registro de eventos contiene información acerca del último archivo no movible que podría limitar el número máximo de bytes reclamables.

 Detalles de diagnóstico:
 - El último archivo no movible parece ser: \ProgramData\Microsoft\Diagnosis\events01.rbs::$DATA
 - El último clúster del archivo es: 0x40b5688
 - Destino potencial de reducción (dirección LCN): 0x20153fa
 - Las marcas de archivo NTFS son: ----D
 - Fase de reducción: <analysis>

 Para obtener más detalles acerca de este archivo, use el comando "fsutil volume querycluster \\?\Volume{d4dd19c7-01e3-11e2-9368-806e6f6e6963} 0x40b5688".
XML de evento:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Defrag" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="16384">259</EventID>
    <Level>4</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2015-12-18T18:29:12.000000000Z" />
    <EventRecordID>56671</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>leon</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>OS (C:)</Data>
    <Data>\\?\Volume{d4dd19c7-01e3-11e2-9368-806e6f6e6963}</Data>
    <Data>\ProgramData\Microsoft\Diagnosis\events01.rbs::$DATA</Data>
    <Data>0x40b5688</Data>
    <Data>0x20153fa</Data>
    <Data>----D</Data>
    <Data>&lt;analysis&gt;</Data>
    <Binary>00000000C7000000AF00000000000000223679625372B2B9637B71360E00000000000000</Binary>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

Note: The events were marked as defrag, I had defragged just before checking the event list, and 2 times, probably that's the reason of two of that kind events. I'm not entirely sure the events are of the defrag or of the disk manager.

Answer (score 0):

There are control records stored high up in the free space. Disk Management cannot move those and will give you only the free space beyond those control records. Use [this program](http://www.partitionwizard.com/resizepartition/free-software-to-resize-partition.html). It can move the control records.

Comment: I want a way to it without 3rd party. That guy's answer in my post was very upvoted, so there should be a way natively.

Comment: If you show me more evidence of those "control records", in form of articles on the web or a test for me to do,  I'll follow your advice.

Comment: Read this. Although it was in the context of Vista, it is still the same. http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/working-around-windows-vistas-shrink-volume-inadequacy-problems/

Comment: You better look again.

Comment: Now I have seen it. I will attempt it.