# How to shrink Windows 7 boot partition with 0 available shrink space

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot, partitioning

I'm trying to shrink a partition that has 140GB of 210GB free. I followed the suggestions here: [How to shrink Windows 7 boot partition with unmovable files](https://superuser.com/questions/88131/how-to-shrink-windows-7-boot-partition-with-unmovable-files) (defragged, turned of restore, recovery, etc) and managed to get about 30GB worth. But now I'm stuck. I can't shrink any further, but it doesn't report any unmovable files. The query runs, and I get an event in the log with ID 258 saying "The disk defragmenter successfully completed shrink estimation on (C:)".

Any suggestions? I'm open to using a third party tool as long as its free. I also have a ubuntu system setup that I could use, though I've read some horror stories about parted making the windows drive unbootable.

Comment: I've tried a bunch of third party defrag tools: Auslogics Disk defrag, Ultra Defrag, PerfectDisk. According to perfectdisk, there's some kind of unmovable block right at the end of my partition. PerfectDisk doesn't give me any useful info, just saying that it's excluded. It doesn't seem to be NTFS metadata, though, as that's listed separately. The Windows shrink tool also doesn't give any useful info as mentioned in op. https://imgur.com/av3sPdB

Comment: I was able to resize the partition by using mini tool partition wizard, and having it run at boot

Answer (score 0):

Have you Configured your Paging File size?

1. Go to Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\System
2. Click on **Advance System Settings**
3. Look for **Performance** and Click the button **Settings**
4. In there, Click the Tab **Advanced**
5. Look for **Virtual Memory** and Click the button **Change**
6. Uncheck the Checkbox "Automatically Manage..."
7. Configure Paging Size, Reduce it to a Safe amount.
8. Try Shrinking Again!

Comment: I have the page file on a different drive

Comment: Is your C Drive has System Managed Paging Size or No Paging Files radio box selected?

Comment: No paging file.